# how to read in one single activity multiple webpage by w

Tags: android

when we clicked button send the local html file path to activity and this activity read in  WebView. Means  multiple button send the different different webpage path to single activity how to do that.

Main Activity

```
Uri uri_path = Uri.parse("file:///android_assets/www/idex.html");

Intent varr1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
varr1.setType("text/html");
varr1.putExtra("name",uri_path.toString());
startActivity(varr1);
```

Second Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(extras.getString("name"));

webView.("uri1","text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: how many buttons you are having?

Comment: In Main Activity six Button